# Basis for quaternionic functions

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series, quaternions

We know that the set of functions $\{1,\cos x, \sin x, \cos 2x, \sin 2x, ... \; | \,x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is a basis in the  space $L^2_\mathbb{R}[-\pi,\pi]$ .

Given a quaternion $z \in \mathbb{H}$ we can analogously define the functions 
$$
\cos nz= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^k\,(nz)^{2k}}{(2k)!} =  \dfrac{e^{nz}+e^{-nz}}{2}  
$$
$$
 \sin nz  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^k\,(nz)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}= \dfrac{e^{nz}-e^{-nz}}{2\mathbf{i}}
$$
where $\mathbf{i}$ is one of the immaginary unit of $\mathbb{H}$.

Is the set $\{1,\cos z, \sin z, \cos 2z, \sin 2z, ... \; | \,z \in \mathbb{H} \}$ a basis for  some suitable space of functions $f:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ ?

Comment: You have to be pretty careful here even defining "span" because you might mean the "left span" or the "right span" (depending on which side the coefficients go on). Same for "basis" -- do you mean "basis as a vector space over $\mathbb R$?", or basis as a vector space over $\mathbb H$ (which doesn't make sense, because $\mathbb H$ isn't a field)?

Comment: I'm thinking to $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces so that  $af(z)=f(z)a$.

Comment: In such case I hope that  also coefficients are reals...